# Intuition of multivariate conditional entropy

Tags: entropy, information-theory, conditional-entropy

This might be a dumb question, but I'm serious.

Per the wiki page about [conditional entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy): quantifies the amount of information needed to describe the outcome of a random variable $Y$ given that the value of another random variable $X$ is known.

My question is what if I know two variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, can I say conditional entropy quantifies the amount of information needed to describe $Y$ given $X_1$ and $X_2$ together?